# swiftui use a non SF Symbols SVG in your project

Tags: svg, swiftui, sf-symbols

If I want to use an SVG specifically that is not in the SF Symbols library, how would I do that?

I have tried dragging and dropping a random SVG of a basketball to my image assets folder that I downloaded from the internet but it will not read in my image assets folder. I am trying to get it so I get easily customize the image itself, changing the colors, weight etc just like you can do with an SF symbol.

Comment: Customizing Symbol Images is not that trivial. Those SVG objects represent not just one image, it's an image set. Please see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom SF Symbol or use this tool to convert SVG to Shape struct: https://quassummanus.github.io/SVG-to-SwiftUI/